# Generating Unique Keys when using Aggregation in MongoDB? How to use $out after $unwind?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

`db.test.find()` provides the following document

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "relatives" : [ 
        "A", 
        "B", 
        "C"
    ]
}
```

after `$unwind` (`db.test.aggregate([{ $unwind : "$relatives"}])`) , if becomes

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "relatives" : "A"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "relatives" : "B"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "relatives" : "C"
}
```

Now if I want to `$out` (`db.test.aggregate([{ $unwind : "$relatives"}, {"$out" : "new_collection"}])`) the document into another collection, I will get a **duplicate Key error**. There is another question where he/she just wanted to remove the duplicate documents. But as you can see, I will need these different documents. And so, I want to recompute the IDs or create unique IDs for each document so that I can $out the collection successfully.

**EDIT 1 :**
I was able to solve this by using a **ForEach** loop...

```
count = 1;
db.test.aggregate([{ $unwind : "$relatives"}]).forEach(function (element){
    element._id = count;
    count++;
    db.new_collection.save(element);
});
```

...but I want to know if there is a more elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: Add {$project:{_id:0}} before out stage.

Comment: But if you do that _id will not be displayed.. I want the _id to be a part of it

Comment: Id will be created when $out aggregation inserts the document. Do you need to create id in the pipeline ? If yes how do you plan to compute them.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue using a lookup to join two collections and create new records in another collection. I ran into an issue because I am using UUID instead of object ID. I ended up using the same foreach solution you created. I am also interested if anyone else has a more elegant/faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

Emit the `_id` with `$project`

use `$out` aggregate for new collection

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$relatives"},
  { $project: {_id: 0,  relatives: 1},
  {$out: "newCollection"}
]));
```